# Cannot Access Private Member: std::copy

Tags: c++, vector, std, ofstream

I'm trying to use std::copy to copy the contents of a vector into an output file.  I'm using the following code:

```
void save()
{
    std::basic_ofstream<TChar> fo(mFilename.c_str());
    std::copy(mContent.begin(), mContent.end(), fo);
}
```

The problem is, I get this error:

Error   2   error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\fstream 802

I've searched for this on SO and everyone seems to be accidentally using the copy constructor when passing parameters.  Since I'm not passing parameters, I'm not sure how the copy constructor is getting fired (or if it's getting fired).

Additional info:

TChar is a template character and is generally of type char, int, wchar_t etc....   In this calling context, I'm using char.

mContent is a vector of type TChar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [std::ostream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator):

```
void save()
{
    std::basic_ofstream<TChar> fo(mFilename.c_str());
    std::copy(
        mContent.begin(), mContent.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<mContent::value_type>(fo, " "));
}
```

Comment: Doh! I knew I was missing something simple.  That makes a ton of sense.  I modified your code slightly and it's working great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Copy takes as a third argument an output iterator not an output stream.  You passed it an output stream.  The error is because if you try to use an output stream as an iterator, lots of errors occur.  That just happened to be the first one.